# Numpy lists from a file

Tags: numpy

I am attempting to read a line of comma separated numbers, each list of numbers delimited from the next by a `'\n'`.
 The function below runs fine through `fh.seek(0)`. I verify by uncommenting the `print`. However, when I try what appears to be the same way of reading the list and inserting it into a `mumpy` `array` from the file [the code after the `seek`], I get an **ERROR**:

```
data = np.array([r.strip().split(',') for r in fh]).astype('float')
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

The code fragment:

```
import numpy as np

def ReadDataFile(self, filename):
        fh = open(filename, 'r')
        for r in fh:
            dataPointStrList= r.strip().split(',')
            #print dataPointStrList
            for x in dataPointStrList:
                dataPoint = float(x)
                #print dataPoint

        fh.seek(0)

        data = np.array([r.strip().split(',') for r in fh]).astype('float')
```

Is this a bug in `numpy`? Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: You're not handling empty lines.

Comment: @user2357112 is correct.

Comment: How to handle empty lines in the list comprehension case in python?

Comment: What is confusing is that I thought strip() already removed empty lines.

Comment: I figured it out. I was just using \r or \n and those are problematic by themselves. If I write the file with both \r\n, the strip works.

Comment: I often demonstrate `genfromtxt` by applying it to a list of strings, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929470/loading-my-data-in-numpy-genfromtxt-get-errors/44931608#44931608

Comment: I should also note that I was also writting out 'nan'  and 'inf' to the file, and those cause problems when being read back into float. The python error system is not very helpful in this case.